# Plotting a function that uses the solutions to a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting

I am trying to draw a plot by using the solution of differential equations

```
z = 0;
Ω = 2.2758;
τ = 13.8;
T2 = 200;
ω0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
Δ = 1.7758;
ΩR = 2.2758;
ω == 0.5;
system = {u'[t] ==  Ω*v[t],
v'[t] ==  Ω*u[t] - 2*ΩR*w[t] - v[t]/T2,
w'[t] ==  2*ΩR*v[t]};
initialvalues = {u[0] ==  0, v[0] ==  0, w[0] ==  -1};
sol = DSolve[Join[system, initialvalues], {u[t], v[t], w[t]}, t]
FT = (-2*2.2758*r*u[t])/ω0^2 E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - (t^2/τ^2))* Cos[kz - ωt];
p1 = 
  Plot[FT, {t, -20, 20}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"t", "FT"}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    RotateLabel -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002]}]
```

[image: my code]

right now I went to plot "FT" by using the result of "u" , How I can do that ?

Comment: Sorry for the mess earlier, I hope the question is clear now

Comment: There are several syntax errors and mistakes in the code, and as there is nothing much else to this question than that, I'm voting to close. A remaining problem is that `kz` is not defined.

Comment: Your solution from `DSolve` is complex. How do you want to plot it in the real plane? You can try to plot `Plot[Re[FT /. sol /. {kz -> .1, \[Omega]t -> .2}], {t, -20, 20}]` to get an idea, but I only guessed at the `kz` and `\[Omega]t` values.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to make your plot with results from solving your system of ODEs.

```
z = 0;
Ω = 2.2758;
τ = 13.8;
T2 = 200;
ω0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
Δ = 1.7758;
ΩR = 2.2758;

ω = 0.5;
```

Note: syntax error corrected in expresion for ω.

```
system = {
  u'[t] == Ω*v[t], 
  v'[t] == Ω*u[t] - 2*ΩR*w[t] - v[t]/T2, 
  w'[t] == 2*ΩR*v[t]
};
initialvalues = {u[0] == 0, v[0] == 0, w[0] == -1};
sol = DSolve[Join[system, initialvalues], {u[t], v[t], w[t]}, t] // Chop // Simplify;
```

I used `Chop` and `Simplify` to get rid of some fuzz produced by `DSolve` because it was given approximate numbers.

```
FT = (-2*2.2758*r*u[t])/ω0^2 E^(-(r^2/ω0^2) - (t^2/τ^2))*Cos[k*z - ω*t]
```

> ```
> -3.21844 E^(-0.49999 - 0.005251 t^2) Cos[0.5 t] u[t]
> ```

Note: syntax errors corrected in the expression for `FT`.

```
Plot[FT /. sol, {t, -20, 20}]
```

[image: plot.png]